# one-to-one and onto function question

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, self-learning

I am trying to understand this exercise:

Let S be the set of all strings of 0's and 1's, and define f: S -> $Z^{nonneg}$ by f(s) = the length of s, for all string in S.

a. Is f one-to-one? The answer in the book is simply, no because f(0) = f(1) = 1 but 1 $\neq$ 0. I understand that there is an f(0) and an f(1) because of the strings of 0's and 1's but I don't see why f(0) = f(1). Could some one explain this?

b. Is f onto? According to the book: f is onto. Suppose n is a non-negative integer. It must be shown that there exists a string a in S such that f(s) = n.
Let s = "the null string" if n = 0 and let s = 000...0 if n > 0. Then f(s) = the length of s = n, as was to be shown. I don't understand this answer.

It would be great if someone could help me understand one or both of these.

Thanks for any help,

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain both answer (a) and answer (b). So set of strings of 0's and 1's could look like this 01111100001; the function f by definition maps such a sequence to a (non-negative integer) namely to "(number of 0's in the string) + (number of 1's in the string)". In my example 01111100001 there are five 0's and six 1's, hence f(01111100001)=5+6=11.

Now, in the string 0 there is one "0" and no "1", hence f(0)=1+0=1. On the other hand, in the string 1 there is no "0" and one "1", hence f(1)=0+1=1. Thus f(0)=f(1).

Why is it onto? Consider a positive integer $n$ for this consider the string $\underbrace{(0,0,0\ldots0)}_n$, then we have that f$((0,0,0\ldots0))$=n+0=n.
Moreover, usually one considers the *zero string* " " to be a string as well, and this is mapped by f to 0. Hence the function f is onto the set of all non-negative integers.

Comment: Hi, am I correct in thinking that f(0)= 1 and f(1) = 1 because the length of each string is 1? But, why do you have f(0)=1+0=1 and f(1)=0+1=1? Why the "1+0" and "0+1"?

Comment: You are absolutely correct,  f(0)= 1 and f(1) = 1 because the length of each string is 1. My 0+1 and 1+0 only referred to that I calculate the length of the string by "number of 1's in the string" + "number of 0's" in the string.

Comment: Okay, thank you for you help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

As the book says it isn't one-one. To see this note that

(0,1) and (1,0) are both lists that map to 2. So it can't be one-one.

To prove it is onto take any non-negative integer n. Then just take the list $\underbrace{(1,1,1\dots1)}_n$ It has length $n$. so for every member of the co-domain there is a member of the domain mapping to it. In other words it is onto.

Comment: Woops, I mixed the words there, it's ok now. Sorry for mistake

Comment: hi user4140, saw that we wrote the answers at the same time. Btw, you explained it very well +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do what I can.

Comment: Hi. Where does the 2 come from? Is it just an arbitrary number you put in the co-domain? If that is the case, then why did you do this and how would you know to do this?

Comment: Well, you could have picked any number really, because there are many different srings of any size. So I took the number 2 because the strings where easy to write. All you really have to do is show that there are many various strings of any size. So both will be mapped to the same number.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance.